# How to join few tables that are extension

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, persistence

I have Team.class and Player.class which are entities there is of course more fields etc. I would like to extend Player to different player types without making changes in Team.class. Best solution will be to remove Player table and make FootballPlayer etc tables inherits Player fields.

The question is how to join different types of player in Team.class if there is no player table but are football and handball player tables?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Team")
public class Team {

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @JoinTable(name = "TeamPlayer", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", nullable = false, updatable = true) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "player_id",
                    nullable = false, updatable = true) })
    private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();




@Entity
@Table(name = "Player")
public class Player extends User {
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "players")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
 private List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
```